# How does one learn to do mathematical modeling?

Tags: self-study, modeling, econometrics

How would one go about learning how to do mathematical modeling? Is there a course or a textbook that you folks would recommend?

When I read scientific papers, I try and solve the models, which helps me understand that particular paper. But how do I start building and solving models for my own research problems?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "mathematical modeling"? Different people use the term different ways.  For instance, are you talking about the process of building a statistical (regression) model, or something more like how Galileo inferred the mathematical form of falling bodies? Or are you talking about computational process models, or something else?

Comment: “Mathematical modeling” to me screams differential equations, at least as the primary tool. Is that what you mean? Perhaps you could give some examples of models like what you’d like to build.

Comment: @Dave, you are right about the differential equations bit- a lot of the papers I have read do use them. An eg. is the [Bass diffusion model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bass_diffusion_model). Then there are papers like [Blei et al. 's](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~blei/papers/BleiNgJordan2003.pdf) (pg. 996-997) where the authors build up a model - starting from assumptions, lemmas &  they move on to solutions. I can't wrap my head around how they are able to describe a phenomenon as a research problem (maybe abstraction is a better word).I feel a little lost when I sit down to do it by myself

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica I think I find regression models a little easier to understand and build- because I have some sense of what the independent and dependent variables are- either from intuition or theory. It gets tougher for me when I try to do things like economic models of demand or papers like [this one](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~blei/papers/BleiNgJordan2003.pdf) (pg. 996-997) where the authors build up a model - starting from assumptions, lemmas &  they move on to solutions.